# Are there Latin words known only by reconstruction from Romance languages?

Tags: vocabulary, romance-languages

I presume that many Latin words  made it to the Romance languages, but were never attested in writing, whether because they were limited to Vulgar Latin or just because by chance no writer used them in texts we now have.

We can still reconstruct the original Latin, particularly if the words are known across the Romance language family.

Is there a list of such words or an article about them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wiktionary has over 350 [reconstructed terms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_reconstructed_terms) for Latin. Each of these have been [proposed by linguists](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Reconstructed_terms) based on etymological evidence. Each page for these terms is described as follows:

> This Latin entry contains reconstructed words and roots. As such, the
>   term(s) in this entry are not directly attested, but are hypothesized
>   to have existed based on comparative evidence.

I eliminated many of the superfluous forms, especially infinitives and the genitive forms, so there are actually more pages in Wiktionary than what is listed here. In some cases there was no first person singular form (of the present active indicative) for an infinitive, so there are forms in this list for which there is no Wiktionary page. If there isn't a page for a given verb, look for the infinitive form.

**Here's the list:**

abanteo, abbato, abbatuo, abbibero, absedium, abyssimus, accapo, accaptio, accapto, accatto, accognito, accolligo, accollo, accomplesco, accordo, accum, acquaerio, acrus, acucla, acutio, adbassio, adiuxto, adminacio, admortesco, adnecai, adnecatu, adneco, adoclo, adpaco, adventura, advero, advitio, aetaticum, affronto, affumo, affundo, agesco, aiunus, alemosyna, alicunus, alima, alisna, allacto, allumino, altio, amaricus, ambito, amicitas, ando, anteanus, apicla, appaco, appariculo, appodio, arbalista, arborus, arcio, ardo, arresto, arripo, asciola, ascla, assalto, assecuro, attitio, attrago, auca, auso, avicellus, aviola, aviolus, baba, babbus, baccinum, baiulivus, bannio, barbatorem, barra, barrum, bassio, basto, bataclum, bellitas, bellitia, bisonium, blancus, blastemo, blastimo, blavus, boscaticum, bragio, brandus, brigna, bullico, cadentia, cadeo, calcea, cancriclus, canile, capitina, cappella, cappellus, capum, carnaceus, casco, casico, catunum, caveola, cavula, certanus, chirurgianus, cicala, cinquaginta, cinque, cinusia, clapo, clubium, cnifus, coactico, cocinarius, combatto, cominitio, commando, complesco, confesso, consutura, contingesco, convito, coratio, cordarius, cosio, coso, crebellum, cremo, cuniclus, damnaticum, dancio, decembrius, deexcito, deintus, delicatio, depano, derectio, derectus, deripo, destrugo, dia, discalceus, disculceus, dismerdo, domino, domnicella, drectus, ergo, excadeo, excadesco, excalceus, excambio, excappo, excarmino, exeligo, exfortio, expavento, experlavo, extorco, extuto, exvento, exvolo, fabello, facia, fallesco, Fata, feminus, fetiolus, fibella, ficco, figico, finesco, fio, flasca, florio, flotus, focacia, fortio, frappo, frictura, frocus, genuclum, glacia, grabo, granica, haleno, halsbergus, harpa, haunio, Hispaniolus, ianuella, iecto, illu, imbibito, imbosco, implio, impositum, imprehendo, inaltio, inaltus, incaldesco, inclago, indenso, indulcesco, ingrevico, interro, intorco, inuxoro, invirdesco, invitio, ioco, iugaster, lacartus, laitus, languio, leviarius, linguaticum, longitanus, lucio, machino, mais, malifatius, mana, maneana, mania, manizo, mas, matrastra, matrina, medullum, melus, metio, metipsimus, minacia, minacio, mino, misculo, mollio, montania, monto, mordo, morio, movo, mucco, mulgo, murrum, musclus, muso, ninnus, nivico, nivo, noco, nomine, oblito, odio, offeresco, offerio, ordio, orgollio, orulo, palatare, palatium, paresco, pariclus, passarus, passo, patrinus, patta, pendico, perdono, peresco, petio, picco, piccus, picto, pincio, pisco, pissio, pittus, plattus, ploppus, plovo, podio, posso, postius, preco, presso, primavera, pulica, punctio, puppa, putio, putrio, quaresima, quassico, quomo, rabia, raso, raspo, reexcapto, refuso, rencus, rendo, renio, repoenitio, ridio, rido, rosico, rossa, ruptio, sagia, sambatum, sanitosus, sapeo, sarclo, scermio, scribio, sedento, sementia, semitarius, sennus, septembrius, sequio, sicilo, smeralda, smeraldus, socra, soliclus, sorbio, spio, strinctus, stuno, subrido, sufferio, suggluttio, superanus, surrupo, tardivus, tasto, tempulum, tenio, timo, tiro, tocco, toppus, torco, tractio, tragino, tremo, trifolum, tripalio, tropo, trudico, turbulo, turbulus, tutellus, tuto, undizo, uso, vera, veranum, versura, vestitura, virdia, visaticum, volto, wadanio, wardo, warnio, werra

Comment: Good answer,, but a link and a sample is better than the full list

Comment: @vectory I thought that links alone were discouraged because of breakages?

Comment: @Restioson wiktionary is durably archived somewhere, I'd hope ;)

Comment: I myself would actually prefer a link *and* the full list, as long as it fits into one answer. De gustibus non disputandum?

Comment: @Cerberus. I agree. It's better that way.

Comment: @ExpeditoBipes: Perfect. And some interesting words, too! I suspect many would have been Vulgar.

Comment: @Cerberus. I also found it very interesting. I didn't know that such a list existed before today.

Comment: It looks very much as if the true list is shorter than what we have here: as if, in an ancestor of this list, several words were specified using two forms, e.g. "abanteo, abanteare", "amicitas, amicitatis", and whoever sorted them treated each form as if it were a separate list entry.

Comment: Seriously?  "Fata"?  That's used frequently in the Aeneid.   A scholarly source would be nice.  Wiktionary is perhaps not that...

Comment: @RosieF. I eliminated the infinitives and the genitive forms.

Comment: @CMonsour. Did you check out the page for [Fata](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Latin/Fata) in Wiktionary? It explains why it's listed. You might also note that Fata doesn't have an entry of its own in [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=fata&la=la). The plural form of fatum was adapted for a different use.

Comment: @ExpeditoBipes Linguistic reconstruction uses sounds laws (Lautgesetze).  You can't reconstruct that a redeployment of a plural took place in the mother language rather than as an areal spread later.  That's total bunk.

Comment: @CMonsour: You may or may not be right. But must you express yourself so forcefully?